# Inventory Management Not Working when using Connect V2

Tags: square-connect

we are adjusting the stock after inserting the catalog object via SDK for the first time, stock is synchronized in Square Account correctly. After updating the stock quantity, it is doubled in variation level stock, even it is not displaying in square dashboard. Whether I'm missing anything or else if there is any solution available?

```
$V1AdjustInventoryRequest = new \SquareConne\Mode\V1AdjustInventoryRequest();

$V1AdjustInventoryRequest->setQuantityDelta((float) 10);

$V1AdjustInventoryRequest->setAdjustmentType('RECEIVE_STOCK');

$api = new \SquareConnect\Api\V1ItemsApi();

// Upsert the Inventory

apiResponse = $api->adjustInventory($location_id, $variation_id, $V1AdjustInventoryRequest);
```

Comment: What do you mean it is doubled, but not displayed in dashboard? The `QuantityDelta` is not the new stock level, but how much to increase it by. (ie if you currently have 5 stock, and you set `QuantityDelta` to 10, the result will be 15.)

Comment: That's right I need to update quantity, how will I do pls suggest me

Comment: In your example you didn't spell `SquareConnect` correctly (in line 1). Did you set the `location_id` and `variation_id` prior to this?

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake when type, I got variation_id from response of upsert catalog object using connect v2. Then we have using connect v1 for inventory management but not working

Comment: Are you receiving any kind of error? It looks correct to me.

Comment: No . I need clarification about how to sync WooCommerce stock to square inventory management.because when I first time updated inventory correctly  then I updated inventory for same item , result will be double of inventory,

Comment: So, the code works, it just doubles your stock? Does it double every time? Because again the code is adding it, it's not the new stock.

Comment: Yes working codes, but stock is double when updating

Comment: Ex: First sync of inventory 10 then updating second sync of inventory 10 for the product, square account inventory for the product is 20, Why?

Comment: If you have 10, then call `adjustInventory` with 10, it will be 20. 10 + 10 = 20. The number you pass to `adjustInventory` will be added to the current stock level.

Comment: Thank u , how to update current stock in inventory..ex I have 10 stock then I need to update 5 stock  in inventory.

Comment: If your inventory went down, you would pass a negative number. If you have 10 and want to go to 5, you would pass `-5` to `adjustInventory`.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful suggestions ..